# Add overlay to CollectionViewCell once it's clicked

Tags: ios

It's there a way to add an semi transparent overlay to a CollectionViewCell on it's clicked? (I want to "darken" the entire cell when a user taps on the cell).

I found a way to change the background color but I don't know if there'a way to add an overlay.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{ [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:232/255.0f green:232/255.0f blue:232/255.0f alpha:1]]; } completion:nil];
}
```

**EDIT**

I added an UIView with a semi transparent background to the Cell once it's tapped:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 172, 210)];
    overlay.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];
    [cell addSubview:overlay];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just creating a new UIView, set its frame to fill the cell, make it semi-transparent and adding it as subview of the cell?

Comment: "It's there a way to add an semi transparent overlay to a CollectionViewCell on it's clicked" Yes, there is.

Comment: I added an UIView to the cell once it's touched. How do I remove it? Im guessing I have to add some code to didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath. @luk2302

Comment: Yes, you can do that by giving the added view a unique `tag` and retrieve that exact view by looking up the tag later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution, I find, is to add to the cell, right from the start, a UIImageView with no image but with a highlighted image:

```
UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil highlightedImage:im];
iv.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[cell addSubview: iv];
```

The result is that the image `im` magically becomes visible in the cell when - and only when - the cell is highlighted (selected).